Tangent Space on Nonsmooth Manifolds?
Recently I've encountered a couple of definitions of the tangent space, and I was searching for a definition suitable for manifolds that are not $C^\infty$. However this post made quite clear that standard definitions fail to have expected properties (namely the space of derivations becomes infinite dimensional) if the manifold is not smooth.
Is there a definition that requires less smoothness (maybe that works even on manifolds that are differentiable only on a subset (that is, transition maps are differentiable only on the image of such subset)? That would be great) to work, and that gives the tangent space all the expected properties?

You might look into (Whitney) stratified spaces. Here the point is not $C^k$ versus $C^\infty$, but rather the presence of singular loci of various dimensions.

... and if you want less smoothness, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25003/what-is-the-order-of-differentiability-of-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-c2-manifold , which is probably too terse for an Answer here.

You should clarify: Are you working with manifolds that are $C^k$-smooth ($1\le k<\infty$) or with topological manifolds? Is there a particular reason you want to work with $C^k$-smooth ($1\le k<\infty$) manifolds? Every such manifold admits a unique $C^\infty$-smooth structure.
